# Making grunt-mocha works with requirejs

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs, mocha.js

Running the following Mocha tests in a browser works, but when I use `grunt mocha` in the command line, I get `Warning: PhantomJS timed out`. I have turned the gruntfile mocha.options.run to false, because, if true, the requirejs do not have the time to run.

Sadly, I cannot find any complete sample on the matter.

the gruntfile contains:

```
mocha: {
  test: {
    src: ['tests/index.html']
  },
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Mocha Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/mocha/mocha.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>

    <script src="../node_modules/mocha/mocha.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        mocha.setup('bdd');
    </script>

    <script src="../node_modules/chai/chai.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var expect = chai.expect;
    </script>

    <script data-main="requireRunner.js" src="../vendor/require-2.1.9.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

requireRunner:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: '/',
  paths: {
    'jquery'        : '../vendor/jquery-2.0.3',
    'underscore'    : '../vendor/underscore-1.5.2',
    'backbone'      : '../vendor/backbone-1.1.0'
  },
  shim: {
    underscore: {
      exports: '_'
    },
    backbone: {
      deps: [
        'underscore',
        'jquery'
      ],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    }
  },
  urlArgs: 'bust=' + (new Date()).getTime()
});

require([
  'tests/models/todoTest'
  ], mocha.run
);
```

todoTest

```
define(['js/models/todo'], function(Todo) {
    describe('Todo', function(){    

        var todo;
        before(function() {
            todo = new Todo();
        })

        it('defaults are ok', function(){
            expect(todo.get('title')).to.equal('');
            expect(todo.get('completed')).to.be.false;
        })
    })
})
```

todo

```
/*global define*/
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function (_, Backbone) {
    'use strict';

    var TodoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        // Default attributes for the todo
        // and ensure that each todo created has `title` and `completed` keys.
        defaults: {
            title: '',
            completed: false
        }
    });

    return TodoModel;
});
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time also trying to run mocha with requirejs, the tests work in the browser but not in the command line where they are not getting executed, really weird.

Comment: please, have a look at my own answer, I have used log:true in the mocha runner and require debugging traces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple little things to make it work properly:

- paths seem to be more tolerant on the browser, path problem can occur only on grunt-mocha (this is not a problem, just a reminder)
- running `grunt mocha` is not enough, `grunt server mocha` is the way, a server has to be up
- using `options:{log: true}` combined with [requirejs debugging traces](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#requirejsonerror) in the index.html is good help

Answer (score 2):

Your post has helped me to set up my grunt-mocha task ! Thx

I had de turn false the mocha.options.run, otherwise grunt-mocha handled no tests (guess requirejs had not time to load as you said)

however I did not have to set up any server to make it works. 
Running `grunt mocha` is plenty enough !

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FdP - Tests</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../app/vendor/mocha/mocha.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mocha"></div>
<script src="../app/vendor/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
<script src="../app/vendor/chai/chai.js"></script>
<script>
    mocha.setup('bdd');
    chai.should();
</script>
<script data-main="specRunner.js" src="../app/vendor/requirejs/require.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my mocha task

```
mocha: {
  test: {
    src: ['test/index.html']
  }
}
```

specRunner.js

```
...
function (testSuite) {
    'use strict';
    require(testSuite.specs, function () {
        mocha.run();
    });
...
```

Grunt-mocha version : `0.4.7`

Comment: Yup: you don't need a server, your tested files have just to be available. In my case, for xhr reasons, I'm serving them through a node / connect / grunt server, that's all :D

Answer (score 0):

I think may be there is some files include error in you test html file. you can go to folder of your html file, double click the file, if test case can run normally in browser, then grunt-mocha can run it too. So, maybe the problem is something like require.js not found.